# Why react changes read-only prop value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I prepared a [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cray-cslso?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for this problem.

I have an array of objects , named webItem in My App function, and I pass webItem as property to the CreateWeb dialog window function.

I assign the webItem property here as web, and if I change any value of this variable, the original webItem is also changes.

I can not see why is this happening?

I even do an Object.assign, but the result is the same.

Please help me...

Comment: Object.assign only copies the first level. Anything deeper and it just makes a reference to it. That is why your web item is not working the way you want.  Take a peek here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how JavaScript works. You're making a new copy of an *array*, but it still contains references to *objects*. In `setWebItem` you're mutating an object, so those changes are reflected everywhere.

To solve the immediate issue you simply have to return a new object instead of modifying the old one (I changed the TypeScript signature a little to make it more typesafe):

```
const setWebItem = (type: keyof WebItem, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const newWeb: WebItem = {
    ...web[index],
    [type]: event.target.value,
  };

  setWeb([
    ...web.slice(0, index),
    newWeb,
    ...web.slice(index + 1, web.length),
  ]);

  event.preventDefault();
};
```